# Batman (1966) episode where they're stuck in a room?

Tags: dc, batman, episode-identification, batman-1966

I'm trying to remember an episode from the 1960's Batman TV show that I saw when I was a kid. I'm not quite sure who the villain was in the episode but I'm pretty sure it had Batman and Robin. The episode was about Batman, Robin, or both being stuck in a room made out of concrete (almost like a dungeon) and I believe they were stuck on some sort of platform that was getting smaller and smaller. There was some thing underneath the platform in water that would've killed Batman and/or Robin if they fell in (which of course, they didn't). Does anyone happen to know what episode this is?

Comment: There are a *lot* of episodes where part one ended with The Dynamic Duo trapped somewhere, facing certain death.

Comment: @Ward I didn't say they were trapped "somewhere"

Comment: @Ward - A lot? I think you mean "all".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing the ending of S02E07 ("[The Spell Of Tut](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1yau0h_batman-1966-s02e07-the-spell-of-tut_tv)") and the start of S02E08; ("[Tut's Case is Shut](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1yavnn_batman-1966-s02e08-tut-s-case-is-shut_tv)").

Robin finds himself trapped on a shrinking platform over a crocodile pit. Batman rappels in and

> saves him at the last minute.

[image]

Comment: That's it! I thought there might of been crocodiles in it, but wasn't sure.

Comment: I think the answer is also "The Spell Of Tut" (S02E07) as S02E08 is more the ending.